# Using two styles in class attribute of HTML Table is not working Properly

Tags: slds, style, plugin-bug

I am using both jquery plugin and slds in class attribute of html table. Jquery plugin is used for Search and Pagination option

But using both in a single class attribute does not work always.Sometime it shows up, sometime it doesn't. What could be the reason?

```
<table class="dataTable slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
```

Data table jquery Plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                                    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
                                    j$('table.dataTable').dataTable({
                                        sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
                                        "sDom": 'Rlfrtip'
                                    });
                                    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the custom or open source library create a namespace for css to avoid the conflict.

See [here](http://avionsalesforce.blogspot.com/2015/12/dealing-with-multiple-jquery-load-and.html)